# Android match parent leaving a right gap

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, fill-parent

As you can see in the screenshot below there is a small gap on the righthand side where the table rows are not matching parent.  It is best viewed in the divider, but everything is not fully matching parent.  I am at my wits end with this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

My end goal is to match my java swing layout that the pc version uses.  All 3 columns the same width.

[image]

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bordered_popupmenu"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/myclient_inspect_title"
            android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
            android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_close_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="x"
            android:textColor="@color/THEME_BAD_COLOR_TEXT"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bordered_popupmenu">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_imageview"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/bordered_popupmenu" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_quantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="(0)"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text='"Item name"'
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_required_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:background="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_strength"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredstrength_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_level"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredlevel_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_dexterity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_requireddexterity_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_constitution"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredconstitution_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_skill"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredskill_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_intelligence"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredintelligence_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_skilltype"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredskilltype_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_increases"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_increases_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:background="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_strength_increase"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_strengthincrease_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_skill_increase"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_skillincrease_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_dexterity_increase"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_dexterityincrease_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_constitution_increase"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_constitutionincrease_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_skilltype_increase"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_skilltype_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_intelligence_increase"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/itempopup_intelligenceincrease_text"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**edit**

Match Parent as suggested makes it much worse
[image]

Comment: Your `<TableLayout>` should have `match_parent` for the `layout_width`. Also, `TableRow`s are horizontal `LinearLayout`s, so you can use weights to make the widths equal. That is, on each child in the equal-width rows, set `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`. You can then set `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` on the `FontTextView`s, to center the text.

Comment: @MikeM. match parent made it much much worse.  I tried the 0dp thing with weight 1 before I posted.  it made everything much worse.

Comment: What is this being used in? When you don't specify, we kind of assume it's an `Activity`'s content layout.

Comment: Sorry mike.  it is a popupwindow.  I have done what you suggested and it is working now for the fonts if I use matchparent for tablelayout.  Thank you!  Not sure if you want to write an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that can be finicky. Anyhoo, I'm good. Nothing major. Please feel free to post an answer yourself with all of the corrections, so you can close out your question in a couple of days, when it lets you accept your own answer. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, there was one more thing I wanted to mention. You can simplify your dividers by putting those `<View>`s directly in the `<TableLayout>`. They don't have to be in `<TableRow>`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since this is being inflated as a popup window I had to set a hardcoded width of the tableLayout.  Thanks everyone for the assistance.

Inflation:

```
// inflate the layout of the popup window
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MyCommandReceiver.activity_game.getSystemService(MyCommandReceiver.activity_game.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
popupItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.window_popup_item, null);

// create the popup window
int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
popupItemPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupItemView, width, height, focusable);
popupItemPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
popupItemPopupWindow.setFocusable(false);

// show the popup window
// which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
popupItemPopupWindow.showAtLocation(finalView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bordered_popupmenu"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/myclient_inspect_title"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_close_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="x"
                android:textColor="@color/THEME_BAD_COLOR_TEXT"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="370dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bordered_popupmenu">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="33dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/bordered_popupmenu" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_quantity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="(0)"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text='"Item name"'
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_description"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_required_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider3"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_strength"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredstrength_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_level"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredlevel_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_dexterity"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_requireddexterity_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_constitution"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredconstitution_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_skill"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredskill_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_intelligence"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredintelligence_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_required_skilltype"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_requiredskilltype_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_increases"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_increases_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider4"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_strength_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_strengthincrease_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_skill_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_skillincrease_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_dexterity_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_dexterityincrease_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_constitution_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_constitutionincrease_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_skilltype_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_skilltype_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_intelligence_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_intelligenceincrease_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_health_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_healthincrease_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_armor_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_armorincrease_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_damage_increase_percent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_damageincreasepercent_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_mana_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_manaincrease_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_elemental_armor_increase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_elementalarmorincrease_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_elemental_damage_increase_percent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_elementaldamageincreasepercent_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_exp_increase_percent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_expincreasepercent_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_gold_increase_percent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_goldincreasepercent_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_luck_increase_percent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_luckincreasepercent_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <com.kisnardonline.helpers.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_popup_item_light_modifier_percent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/itempopup_lightmodifierpercent_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

make `TableLayout`'s `android:layout_width` to `match_parent` from `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1):

change your all `View` to this

```
<View
            android:id="@+id/divider3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:background="@color/THEME_LIGHT_TEXT" />
```

**NOTE**

If you want to set row to `match_parent` you have to use `android:layout_weight="1"` & don't use `layout_width` for that `view`

Answer (score 1):

Use parent width as match_parent.

here:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

and here:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bordered_popupmenu">
```